# Bootstrap Modal not working inside mdl-layout__content

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, material-design, material-design-lite

I have a project where I, have existing Bootstrap code and now we are migrating to material design lite. Everything work fine in bootstrap code as well as MDL. The main layout page has rendering class as

```
    <body>

<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header mdl-layout--fixed-drawer">
    <header class="mdl-layout__header">
        <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
            <!-- Title -->
            <span class="mdl-layout-title">Procument</span>
            <!-- Add spacer, to align navigation to the right -->
            <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
            <!-- Navigation. We hide it in small screens. -->
            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--expandable
                  mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-textfield--align-right">
                <label class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon"
                       for="fixed-header-drawer-exp">
                    <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                </label>
                <div class="mdl-textfield__expandable-holder">
                    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" name="sample"
                           id="fixed-header-drawer-exp">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="demo-drawer mdl-layout__drawer">

        <header class="demo-drawer-header">


            <img src="~/Content/images/user.jpg" class="demo-avatar"/>
            <div class="demo-avatar-dropdown">

                <span>hello@example.com</span>

                <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>

                <button id="accbtn" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--icon">

                    <i class="material-icons" role="presentation">arrow_drop_down</i>

                    <span class="visuallyhidden">Accounts</span>

                </button>

                <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-right mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="accbtn">

                    <li class="mdl-menu__item">hello@example.com</li>

                    <li class="mdl-menu__item">info@example.com</li>

                    <li class="mdl-menu__item"><i class="material-icons">add</i>Add another account...</li>

                </ul>

            </div>

        </header>

        <nav class="demo-navigation mdl-navigation">

            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"><i class="mdl-color-text--blue-grey-400 material-icons" role="presentation">home</i>Dashboard</a>

            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="@Url.Action("Fileupload", "Home")"><i class="mdl-color-text--blue-grey-400 material-icons" role="presentation">inbox</i>Upload</a>

            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="@Url.Action("Report", "Home")"><i class="mdl-color-text--blue-grey-400 material-icons" role="presentation">delete</i>Report</a>
            <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>

            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""><i class="mdl-color-text--blue-grey-400 material-icons" role="presentation">help_outline</i><span class="visuallyhidden">Help</span></a>

        </nav>

    </div>
    <main class="mdl-layout__content">
        @RenderBody()
    </main>
</div>

</body>
```

The modal doesnot work on **mdl-layout__content** as I, have tried with MDL modal also. The limitation of modal is that it need to be direct child of body. However I, am using bootstrap modal the modal appears in screen but it overlay on the screen.

Here is the code for the modal

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Report";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        Launch demo modal
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I, have many page with each page their is the modal required. I, can't add all modal to the layout file.

The main cause of error is **mdl-layout__content** class. If I don't include this class my design is not looking good.

How can I solve this issue.

Here are the few issue raised by the people
https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/4038

Here is the screen shot
[image]

CSS from MDL File

```
 .mdl-layout__drawer.is-visible {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0); }
    .mdl-layout__drawer.is-visible ~ .mdl-layout__content.mdl-layout__content {
      overflow: hidden; }
.mdl-layout__content {
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
      -ms-flex-positive: 1;
          flex-grow: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; }
  .mdl-layout--fixed-drawer > .mdl-layout__content {
    margin-left: 240px; }
  .mdl-layout__container.has-scrolling-header .mdl-layout__content {
    overflow: visible; }
  @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .mdl-layout--fixed-drawer > .mdl-layout__content {
      margin-left: 0; }
    .mdl-layout__container.has-scrolling-header .mdl-layout__content {
      overflow-y: auto;
      overflow-x: hidden; } }
```

You can find the whole css file here

Comment: could you provide a working snippet?

Comment: I have added the full code .. I don't know how to put on snippet sorry.

Comment: It's ok but I need to see the css of `mdl-layout__content`

Comment: @Mdh Alaa Alhaj - I have added the css file and link to the whole css file

Comment: I resolve it by removing z-index: 1; But I don't know is this correct or not. it works but is their any better solution